# Dealing with a large Kronecker product in Matlab

Tags: matrices, optimization, matlab, least-squares, frobenius-method

Following is my minimization problem to solve for matrix D:

$$P=BDB^{T}$$

where dimension of $B$ is $576 \times 1296$ and dimension of $P$(unsymmetric) is $576\times 576$ and
$D$ is a diagonal matrix of dimension $1296 \times 1296$.

To tackle this problem, I am doing the following:

Firstly, I used vector operation:

$$vec(P)= vec(BDB^T) = (B\otimes B)vec(D)$$

Since matrix D is diagonal, we can only choose columns of $B\otimes B$ corresponding to diagonal entries of matrix D.

When I try to implement this in Matlab, I ran into a memory problem. Can anyone help me fix this?

My matlab code looks like the following:

`kronBB = kron(B,B); % kronecker product % 
D = eye(size(B,2)); 
vecD = D(:); 
in = find(vecD); % non-zero indices of vector D % 
kronBB1 = kronBB(:,in) % Only keeping columns corresponding to the diagonal entries of matrix D ;`

Error in matlab reads:

`Requested 576x576x1296x1296 (4151.9GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information. Error in kron (line 34) K = reshape(A.*B,[ma*mb na*nb]);`

Comment: Do you want to solve the lifted linear system, or why do you want to calculate the Kronecker product explicitly? Kronecker lifting is most often useful if you can get around constructing the full product, and just work with the representation implicitly.  
As an aside, it looks like you are doing something wrong - the array size given above seems to be for a 4d array, and not a 2d array as the Kronecker product should be. But I'm not sure this will help with the memory problem.

Comment: I am trying to solve a minimization(inf-norm) problem to solve for diagonal matrix D when matrices A and B are given and have the relation: $A=BDB^T$. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: hmm, since $D$ is diagonal it seems very close to the spectral decomposition/diagonalization $A=QSQ^T$ of a symmetric matrix (which $A$ must be). I'm not entirely convinced your problem will have a solution for arbitrary $B$.

Comment: If most of your coefficients are zero, try using the sparse command: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html

A sparse matrix object is a list of nonzero values and their coordinates, which might be a lot smaller than a regular matrix.

Comment: Thanks for having taken into account my advice. Besides, you clearly have to bypass the construction of $K:=B  \otimes B$ ; this can be done by using the fact that the generic entry of this matrix is $K_{i+k*n,j+\ell*n} = B_{i,j}*B_{k,\ell}.$

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate it further? And also give me an idea how to implement it in matlab? Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't informed of your answer because you hadn't prefixed it by my @username . My remark above comes from the fact that, by the very definition of $B \otimes B$, this matrix is made by assembling blocks $b_{i,j}B$ each one with size $n \times n$. The Matlab implementation would consist into a matching, among all column indices $j+\ell*n$ (my notation) of those that you select with your procedure (in=find...)

Comment: I have assumed $B$ is square. In fact, if $B$ is $m \times n$, the formula for the generic element of $K=B \otimes B$ becomes $k_{i+k*m,j+\ell*n} = b_{i,j}*b_{k,\ell}.$ with $0 \leq i \leq m-1$, $0 \leq j \leq n-1$ (of course with Matlab indices begin at 1: you must do the adequate changes).

Comment: @Jean Marie  Thank you for your answer. But I am still not clear. Could you perhaps write a matlab code so that I can understand better?

Comment: See my program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Matlab program giving you what you call "kronBB1" under two forms : $U$ (direct, as you do) and $V$ (the way I advise) with my formula that I have inplemented as a set of Kronecker products of column vectors (that are still column vectors) without memory issues. This program checks that $U$ and $V$ are the same :

> ```
> clear all;
> m=7;n=12; % for example
> % direct method giving U (with memory issues for big m and n):
> B=round(9*rand(m,n))
> D=kron(B,B);
> U=D(:,n*(0:(n-1))+(1:n)); % straightforward "good column indices"
> % indirect method giving V (without memory issues):
> V=zeros(m^2,n);
> for q=1:n
>     V(:,q)=kron(B(1:m,q),B(:,q));% "1D" Kronecker products
> end;
> max(max(abs(U-V))),% checking U and V are identical
> ```

Comment: Have you now overcome the "dimension malediction" with matrix V ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @JeanMarie. I am able to resolve it for now but there is still a problem if I choose a matrix with larger dimension than I am using it now.

Comment: I  discovered a contradiction in your problem : you say that the LHS is non symmetric whereas the RHS is symmetric...

Comment: But maybe it is not a contradiction, but it means that if you want to minimize $\|P-BDB^T\|$, you will have mainly to look for the closest-to-$P$ symmetric and even positive definite matrix.